# Change status bar of simulator clones for UI tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, simctl

When enabling parallel testing in the ui test scheme, Xcode automatically spawns several clones of the simulator that is used for the tests. Additionally my workflow takes screenshots while testing. I know that I have to use the command `xcrun simctl --set testing` to interact with cloned simulators (e.g. to change the status bar).

However, the clones are not booted at the time of the scheme execution but right before the actual testing starts. I can't use a pre-action here to change the status bar because at that time the clones do not exist yet.

So how can I adjust the status bar of the clones after they've been booted but before the testing starts?

Comment: thanks for teaching me about `--set testing`!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested Test pre-action?

[image: Test pre-action in scheme]

Have you tried to launch xcrun with absolute path like this?

```
/usr/bin/xcrun simctl
```